# Resize all the images in a genarator with cv2 (MedMNIST)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, opencv, generator

I've been experimenting on MedMNIST data and I noticed that the default loader produces 28x28x3 images.
I wanted to resize all images via cv2 to 32x32x3
I previously tried this method but my CNN models fail to achieve good accuracy.

```
 def regen(generate):
  for i, j in generate:
    a= np.zeros((64, 32, 32, 3))
    a[:,2:30,2:30,:]=i
    b = a/255
  yield  b, j
```

Here is a link to the original dataset
https://medmnist.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you tried before, but you can try resizing the images using [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.resize):

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('my_image.jpg')
res = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(32, 32))
```

You can also try changing the `interpolation` argument which defaults to `INTER_LINEAR`, but there are others that may work better for your case. The possible values from the documentation I linked:

- INTER_NEAREST - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
- INTER_LINEAR - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
- INTER_AREA - resampling
  using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image
  decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is
  zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method.
- INTER_CUBIC - a
  bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
- INTER_LANCZOS4 - a
  Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood